# Having trouble totaling value from steppers to total display

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am trying to build this form that totals a quantity then multiplies, by a value and returns total.

Here is a codepen of what I have tried so far http://codepen.io/Ongomobile/pen/grZJvO  Thanks so much for any help!

Here is my function so far

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input-stepper').inputStepper();
});

$(".input-stepper").keyup(getTotals)

function getTotals() {
  var subTotal = 0;
  // for each div of steppers
  $('.input-stepper').each(function() {
    // get values from this div
    var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
    var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
    var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
    $('.multTotal', this).text($total);
    subTotal += $total;

  });
  $("#grandTotal").text(subTotal);
}
```

Comment: @Shaunak Thanks for some lame reason I always have trouble with formating

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working properly, however, I'm assuming you're expecting clicking on the `+` and `-` to change the total as well. Right now you're only listening to the `keyup` event on the inputs themselves. You also need to add a click handler on the buttons such as:

```
$(".input-stepper button").mouseup(getTotals);
```

Note that you should find a more efficient jQuery selector for the buttons though (such as adding them to a class and selecting that directly rather than the nested jQuery reference).

Comment: Thanks Michael I will try

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using jquery.input-stepper.js
this Js documentation states that if you want execute any function on "+/-" button you need to use

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('increase', function (e, amount, plugin) {
   alert('increase with: ' + amount);
});

$('input[type="text"]').on('decrease', function (e, amount, plugin) {
   alert('decrease with: ' + amount);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Sandeeproop you are right about the library I need to take more time to read docs

Comment: What i want to do is each stepper takes a quantity input then multiplies by a value and returns to var to be totaled of all steppers